# want to give printer command on click event in php

Tags: php

i have six different tickets on my standalone application, developed in php. Corresponding to these tickets, i want to give print command to printer directly without printer dialog.

I follows the printer function from php manual
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php

My printer is thermal printer works on LPT port

Comment: This is not possible using PHP alone, because PHP executes on the server

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-write.php#46056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print command to printer without printer dialog is possible using mozila firefox

May be, it is helpful to you

> Open mozila firefox
>
> write at address bar  **about:config**
>
> print. save_print_settings = True - (default):

This process bypass the dialog box appearing again and again

Comment: if i've connected more then one printer then wht behavior it shows

Comment: work only default printer set by you .. in configuration you can set important printer setting ...

Comment: okey, Thanks it is working for my printer dialog problem

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to print without the printer dialog unless you have specialized software for the host device (i.e. the computer sending the print job).

Comment: i have thermal printer that perform this job. It works on LPT port

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it's not possible at all... See:
[How to force a website to print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127646/how-to-force-a-website-to-print)

You it's rather easy to print with the dialog box, however...

`window.print()`

Comment: this option looks better for me

Comment: could you provide any link for more detail.... I am feeling good from this page  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121               ...... from above link i can print whole page but i want to print particular block on the page