# How I can print PDF file?

Tags: javascript, spring, pdf

I need to open PDF file in browser print dialog. This code return PDF, but when  I click href in browser, file save on disk. How can I change it?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task/{taskId}/file", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
        @ResponseBody
        public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> getTaskFile(@PathVariable Long taskId) {
            final String login = SecureUtil.usernameFromSecureContext();
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                Optional<Task> taskOpt = taskService.findOne(taskId, login);

               if (!taskOpt.isPresent()) {
                    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
                }

               taskOpt.map((task) -> TaskUtil.getFileId(task).map(ls -> ls.stream().findFirst().get()).get());
                Task task = taskOpt.get();
                Optional<List<String>> fileIdOpts = TaskUtil.getFileId(task);
                if (!fileIdOpts.isPresent()) {
                    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
                }

               String filePath = fileIdOpts.map(ls -> ls.stream().findFirst().get()).get();
                FileSystemResource fsr = new FileSystemResource(filePath);

                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                String fileName = getFileNamePrefix(task.getAnchor()) + task.getId();

                headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "pdf"));
                headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName + ".pdf");

               return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(fsr);
            }, executorService);
        }
```

Comment: You can't. It's up to the user to print it, if they want to. You can't force people to print stuff from a browser. This would be a massive security issue if any web site could print whatever it wanted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a website to print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127646/how-to-force-a-website-to-print)